# Comparing and Finding row value in DataTable C#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, datatable

I have a DataTable filled with database table (two columns) `id` and `class`. I want to compare the column `class` value with **string** and find the corresponding `id` value. The `classID` should be `int` type.

**My code:**

```
    int classID = from DataRow row in dtClassesDb.Rows where
                  row.ItemArray[1].ToString().Equals(table.TableName) 
                  select row.ItemArray[0];
```

Comment: If you are interested at efficient queries, you could consider creating an index in the `DataTable`, by creating a `DataView`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109550/do-ado-net-datatables-have-indexes) question.

Comment: I have read the link question. But in my case how would i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `Id` from a `DataTble` by comparing column `class` value with any given string.

```
int classID = (int) dtClassesDb.AsEnumerable().
                FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>(1) == "YourStringToCompare").
                ItemArray[0];
```

Here:

- `Field<string>(1)` is using column `class` index which is 1
- `ItemArray[0]` is using column `Id` index which is 0

This is supposed to solve the query to get the `Id`.